# Objective C BitConverter Equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, c, objective-c

I'm wondering if there is an Objective C equivalent to .Net's BitConverter.GetBytes() method.

For example, in C#, I can write something like this:

byte[] lengthPrefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(message.length);

What would the equivalent be in Objective C?

Some example code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need a specific endian-ness:

```
unsigned char * lengthPrefix = (unsigned char *)&message.length;
```

Or, copy to a 32-bit buffer, if needed.

```
unsigned char lengthPrefixBuffer[4];
memcpy(lengthPrefixBuffer, &message.length, 4);
```

Comment: You are taking the address of a temporary returned integer. Does this compile? It might be in a register...
 `NSInteger length = message.length; unsigned char *lengthPrefix = (unsigned char*)&length;`

Comment: +1 albeit not pretty should work (NSInteger == long) although I probably would have used sizeof just in case in the memcpy version.

Comment: There are a whole load of functions in Foundation to do endian related byte swapping.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_181

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  The following achieved the desired results:

NSInteger length = [msgData length]; 
unsigned char *lengthPrefix = (unsigned char*)&length;

unsigned char lengthPrefixBuffer[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
memcpy(lengthPrefixBuffer, (unsigned char *)lengthPrefix, 4);

Thanks again, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sin Objective-C is C in its roots, you can use bitwise operators to accomplish something similar.

There is nothing on the COCOA/COCOA-TOUCH framework that will do that automatically for you (like's .NET's BitConverter).

Answer (score 0):

byte[] lengthPrefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(message.length);
equivalent for that would be

```
long ID = length;   
Byte *some = (Byte*)&ID;
    Byte b1 = some[0];
    Byte b2 = some[1];
    Byte b3 = some[2];
    Byte b4 = some[3];
Byte lengthPrefix[]= {b1,b2,b3,b4};
```

The main idea how many bytes you need...
so somewhere before this operation specify what length you want and how many bytes you want. So for long it is enough 4 bytes. For uint32 you probably need more.